# I can't install Broadcom driver on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom

After installing Linux Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Lenovo V580c, I can't install Broadcom Wi-Fi adapter driver. After "Applying changes..." nothing happens.

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Did you open the 'Additional Drivers' tool and download the drivers (via LAN/Ethernet)?  Did you reboot after the drivers were installed?  What steps have you done so far to debug this?  (This question is unclear because it is missing details)

Comment: "Did you open the 'Additional Drivers' tool and download the drivers (via LAN/Ethernet)?" - Yes, I did, but driver doesn't install.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: I added information about the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if we can get the driver to install correctly. With a temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Please open Software and Sources and uncheck the source CDROM and/or USB so that the system doesn't try to install from the USB but instead downloads from the internet. Then try the commands above once more.

Post any errors or messages and we'll proceed.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
......
Do you want to continue? [Y / n] y
Media Change: insert the disc labeled
  «Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)"
into the «/ media / cdrom /» and press enter
(I used translate.google.com because I have another system language)

Comment: Are you able to insert the DVD? Can you instead get a temporary internet connection by ethernet or tethered or whatever means? Your translation is just fine!!

Comment: "Your translation is just fine!!" - Sarcasm? I installed the system from a USB drive. Now I use my android phone as a modem. If you do not understand the translation, I will briefly try to explain: after the command terminal asks me to insert the installation disk with Linux.

Comment: Not sarcasm at all. I understand perfectly. Please try inserting the USB and press Enter.

Comment: without any changes

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and do the following,

```
sudo rmmod -f acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

check the wifi is working fine,

Comment: neo@neo-Lenovo-V580c:~$ sudo rmmod -f acer-wmi
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'acer_wmi': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module acer-wmi: No such file or directory

Comment: doesn't work :c

Comment: @vembutech How could you possibly think he has an Acer laptop??